# .htaccess causing website to show 500 internal error at some intervals

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hello everyone my website works well sometimes, while at some interval it displays 500 internal server error. When i refresh it, it displays the correct content. removing the .htaccess file, it works well. Below is my .htaccess file, can someone tell me if it contains any errors that might be prompting the internal server error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/s/([0-9]+)/(.*)html$ videos/funny/index.php?vid=$1&p=$2&s=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ business/each-news.php?tid=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/s/([0-9]+)/(.*)html$ business/index.php?fid=$1&p=$2&s=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^musics/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/s/([0-9]+)/(.*)html$ music/hip-hop/index.php?mid=$1&p=$2&s=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^music/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ music/hip-hop/music-each.php?jid=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/p/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ videos/funny/video_each.php?jid=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is 'some intervals'? Every now and then? Did you not check to see if the problem occurs on specific URIs?

Comment: The errors occur mostly when i click on the rewrited links